# Gremlin sideEffect variable assignment doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I'm trying to accomplish vertex-wise subgraph matching using the following construct:

```
a = g.v(1) 
p = g.v(5) 

a.filter{it.map() == p.map()}.out.sideEffect{p = p.out}.loop(3){it.object != null}
```

I should say that the map comparison surprisingly works well enough, but the side effect part does not seem to modify the `p`-vertex in a proper way. When I print `p` after performing these Gremlin steps - it looks like a pipeline. But more explicit `p = g.v(p.out.id)`, `p = g.v(p.outE.inV.id)` and even numeric `i++` side effects do not seem to modify the value at all.

I tried this both in Neo4j Gremlin shell, and through Groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a pipeline when you expect something else, try a next() to see if that gets you what you want.  Note that when I next() in the sideEffect closure, x changes.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> x = g.v(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V.out.sideEffect{x = x.out.next()}   
==>v[2]
gremlin> x
==>v[2]
```

Comment: Thanks. While it works in the console, it doesn't in my Groovy class: 
`def t = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()`   
`println t`
`def x = t.v(1)`
`println x`
t.V.out.sideEffect{x = x.out.next()}   
println x`
I get: `tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
v[1]
v[1]`

Comment: in the gremlin console it iterates the pipeline for you.  don't you just need to iterate() in your groovy class to force the sideEffects to occur?  In other words, just do: t.V.out.sideEffect{x = x.out.next()}.iterate()